# Problem with creating a session variable and using it in different module

Tags: event-observer, onepage-checkout, session

I set a session variable through ajax request like in checkout page

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyValue($value_from_post_data);
```

The above is set in a controller of a One Page Checkout module.

I have an event observer which `observes checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` here, when I access the session, I don't find my_value the session variable I created.

Note: The session ids are same. No change in them. After the session value is set, I printed the whole session data to confirm, the `setMyValue` created my_value in the session.

So the ajax request has done its job. It has set the variable But the observer picks up old session data. Why is this happening, give me a work around

Comment: On which controller you have  set session varibale

Comment: use  Mage::getSingleton('core/session') instead of Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')

Comment: @AmitBera : I ve tried all the three Core , customer and checkout. I ve set it in a custom controller which handles AJAX request. The session was set through AJAX

Comment: then create quote variable and order variable  .On ajax request  set the value at that quote  variable it automatically set to order new field

Comment: @AmitBera : I am kind of confused about that. can you elaborate a little bit more. I am new to magento

Comment: Can you please tell me on checkout steps are you want to set this session varible

Comment: Ok Simple. I have to fetch a child_name from a custom form and save it in a table with the created order_id after success of onepage checkout. The rest all are the same process.

Comment: when you have fill customer form? before checkout or after order place?

Comment: before checkout along with one page checkout form

Comment: how many field  are you want to save it in Session variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said that your form is exit in Checkout step then we can set field value at Quote  Object and then you can `get this quote variable value from order`   at success page which fill you requirement.

**Step1:** Create new field at Sale Quote table  and Order table  using installer

```
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("quote", "customfield", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->addAttribute("order", "customfield", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Step2:**  On your Custom controller save this field to new quote field

```
    if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getId()){
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setCustomfield($yourFieldValue)->save();
    }
```

**Step3:** We have used  copy field logic for copy Quote field  value to Order field value.

```
<global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                          
                <customfield><to_order>*</to_order></customfield>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                             
                <customfield><to_quote>*</to_quote></customfield>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
```

Please [Study:](https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/how-to-create-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento/)about  this

**Step4:**  Then you can easy get this field value from Order object

```
$OrderObejct->getCustomfield();
```

### Full Module:

**Step1:** Create Module at `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento51524/etc/config.xml`

code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento51524>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento51524>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <magento51524>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento51524_Helper</class>
      </magento51524>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <magento51524>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento51524_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento51524_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento51524>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <salesattribute1420712691_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Stackexchange_Magento51524</module>
          <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </salesattribute1420712691_setup>
      <salesattribute1420712691_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </salesattribute1420712691_write>
      <salesattribute1420712691_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </salesattribute1420712691_read>
    </resources>
    <events>
      <checkout_submit_all_afte> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_afte_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento51524/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>ownfieldValueset</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_submit_all_afte_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_submit_all_afte>
    </events>
  </global>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                          
                <customfield><to_order>*</to_order></customfield>
            </sales_convert_quote>
            <sales_convert_order>                                             
                <customfield><to_quote>*</to_quote></customfield>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step2:** Create  Installer file at `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento51524/sql/salesattribute1420712691_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

And code is:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("quote", "customfield", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->addAttribute("order", "customfield", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Step3:** Create `Helper class` at `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento51524/Helper/Data.php`

Code is

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento51524_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**Step4:** Observe file :  at  `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento51524/Model/Observer.php`

A nd code

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento51524_Model_Observer
{

    public function ownfieldValueset(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success', array('user'=>$user));
        //$user = $observer->getEvent()->getUser();
        //$user->doSomething();
    }

}
```

**Step5:** Create `Stackexchange_Magento51524.xml` which used for  Module config at   app\etc\modules\

Code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento51524>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento51524>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Step:On your submit controller add this code for set the field to new quote fields

Comment: That is definitely an awesome work around. I am going for this way. Thanks. But why is the session not working / updating. Is that a bug in magento or is there a way where I can actually ask magento to refresh the session something like for example refreshSessionObject() after an update so that I dont have to wait till the page reloads.

Comment: On checkout order place session variable has been unset thus it may be create issue.